# PostSharp -- Apply attribute to all private fields

Tags: attributes, postsharp

I would like to apply an attribute, (e.g. `<DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)>`) to all private fields in a class.

How can I accomplish this with PostSharp?

I have tried applying the following aspect to the classes, but without success.

```
<MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Class)>
<Serializable>
Public Class DebuggerBrowsableHidePrivateMembersAttribute
   Inherits TypeLevelAspect
   Implements IAspectProvider

   Public Iterator Function ProvideAspects(targetElement As Object) As IEnumerable(Of AspectInstance) Implements IAspectProvider.ProvideAspects

      Dim targetType = targetElement.GetType

      Dim aspect = New CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect(New ObjectConstruction(targetType, DebuggerBrowsableState.Never))

      For Each field In targetType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)

         Yield New AspectInstance(field, aspect)

      Next

   End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following aspect:

```
Imports PostSharp.Aspects
Imports PostSharp.Extensibility
Imports PostSharp.Reflection

<MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Field Or MulticastTargets.Property)>
Public NotInheritable Class DebuggerBrowsableHideMembersAttribute
   Inherits LocationLevelAspect
   Implements IAspectProvider

   'Hides the following members from browsable debugger windows.
   '  Private Fields
   '  Protected Fields
   '  Static (Shared) Fields
   '  Private Properties
   '  Protected Properties
   '  Static (Shared) Properties
   '  Indexed Properties

   Private Shared ReadOnly Aspect As New CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect(New ObjectConstruction(GetType(DebuggerBrowsableAttribute), DebuggerBrowsableState.Never))

   Public Iterator Function ProvideAspects(targetElement As Object) As IEnumerable(Of AspectInstance) Implements IAspectProvider.ProvideAspects

      Dim location = DirectCast(targetElement, LocationInfo)

      Select Case location.LocationKind

         Case LocationKind.Field
            Dim info = location.FieldInfo

            If info.IsPrivate OrElse info.IsFamily OrElse info.IsStatic Then
               Yield New AspectInstance(location.FieldInfo, Aspect)
            End If

         Case LocationKind.Property
            Dim info = location.PropertyInfo.GetMethod
            If info.IsPrivate OrElse info.IsFamily OrElse info.IsStatic OrElse info.GetParameters.Count > 0 Then
               Yield New AspectInstance(location.PropertyInfo, Aspect)
            End If

      End Select

      Exit Function

   End Function

End Class
```